# How to increase the timeout for a web application

Tags: linux, timeout

I have a web application which is processing some data on server side. I am requesting this process with a post request.

The problem is that if I have a big amount of data, I will get a timeout.
I am usig a ngnix server with PHP.

The error I am getting is 404 Not Found.

Do you know how is it possible to increase the timeout?

Thank you.

Comment: Either there is a configuration option to specify a higher timeout or you have to edit the source code of the web application in question.

Comment: Thank you @scai, but where to find the configuration option on the server, or in the browser?

Comment: Which is the server? Apache? And which is the language of the server side page? Php? Asp? Tell us more

Comment: It is a ngnix server and the language used is the PHP. Sorry for missing those information.

Comment: In php you can use `max_execution_time = 60` inside php.ini. 60 seconds is just an example. This link will help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829403/how-to-increase-the-timeout-in-php

Comment: Thank you @Suku, So i have to do this on my local machine right? Not on the server side?

Comment: Of course, on server side. Server is executing php script and hence you need to make this change on server side.

Comment: Of course, sorry, stupid question. But, there is no timeout also in the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### PHP

To increase PHP execution timeout, increase in php.ini. To see where your php.ini is located, see phpinfo().

```
max_execution_time = 60 #this is in seconds
```

### nginx

To increase nginx's timeout on reading from backend, increase in nginx config (nginx/nginx.conf).

```
proxy_read_timeout 60
```

More: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_read_timeout

### cURL

This is an assumption, but since you say you are making a POST request, increase cURL timeout

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 400); //timeout in seconds
```

More: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

### Misc

Be sure to set timeouts with precedence in mind. PHP will keep processing even if nginx decided to stop listening. etc.

Comment: Thank you very much @Peter, in fact, I am using a backend application to process data and I am getting a 404 not found error after something like 15 seconds, éore and less. Which solution should I use in this case?

Comment: I don't know how you are exactly pulling that data. Could it be actually not found -- ie 404? Timeouts shouldn't technically give you a 404 error. Timeout is 408. But if timeout is really the cause, you'd want to increase all of them to at least maximum you set on cURL (if you're using curl). nginx >= php >= curl.

Comment: Hm, ok. Strange. But if I will change for example the max_execution_time I will need to restart the php, right?

Comment: Yes, restarting the php processor is required, as is nginx reload.

Comment: Ok, I think i will try to find another solution because this code is running on our production server and I can't restart it. Thank you very much for your help, I will confirm your answer.